# How to declare a Flow type for objects used as maps that excludes functions

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Function is compatible with `{}` type:

```
/* @flow */
const a = { 'foo': {} }
const b = () => true;

(a: {[string]: {} });  // No errors! Cool, I like it
(b: {[string]: {} });  // No errors! Not cool, I don't want functions to pass validation
```

Is it possible to somehow exclude functions but allow dictionaries?

[Try Flow example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxnAdgZwC5gCGYAvGAN5gDkUccVAXBQL5jMbb5gBGpYAFAEpSAPjB4ATgFcApgG5UYJWFT9CTcgG18EgJZYA5gF0NrZoLlLgwMADk4YGRIlwJOAIRgAwnRhgAkmAwugDWMmC6eKrcGtqS+sambBZWNvaOzq4ednAEmHAwADQBYAAm2FQECIRYBFBSWOh4upziDgAOhDg4YABuhMGlhM3YQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid because functions are technically valid Objects. However, you can get around this with a bit of a hack: Set an optional property `$call` and give it an `empty` type:

```
/* @flow */
const a = { 'foo': {} }
const b = () => true;

(a: { $call?: empty, [string]: {} });  // No errors! Cool, I like it
(b: { $call?: empty, [string]: {} });  // Errors, woohoo!
```

This works due to Flow's internal definitions of Functions. To explain, I'll show how you can assign an Object to a function type by giving it a `$call` property:

```
/* @flow */
const obj = { $call: () => { console.log('wat'); } };
(obj: Function)  // No errors
```